# Equation of circle through three given points.

Tags: geometry, circles

Yes, there are many methods to find the equation; the easiest being the process of solving the eqn. of circle putting the three points. But what I didn't understand is the another method which my book describes as:

> If three points be $A$ , $B$ , $C$ , then write $S$ = equation of circle on $AB$ as diameter.
>   $P$ = equation of line through $A$, $B$ .

The required equation of the circle is $$ S + \lambda . P = 0$$ , where $\lambda$ is found by passing it through the point $C$ .

What did the book do here?? Why should the circle have $AB$ as diameter and how does the equation represent the circle passing through $A , B , C$ ? It chose a circle having $AB$ as diameter. But the circles passing through these three points can have any diameter. So, why $AB$? How can the equation be the equation of the required circles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can the equation be the equation of the required circles???

It described the family of circles passing through $A$ and $B$, and then picked the appropriate element from that family.

If you have a point $(X,Y)$ on a circle with center $(x,y)$ and radius $r$, its equation is

$$r^2=(X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2=X^2-2Xx+x^2+Y^2-2Yy+y^2$$

which is of the form $(X^2+Y^2)+aX+bY+c=0$ with $a=-2x,b=-2y,c=x^2+y^2-r^2$. So as long as $4c<a^2+b^2$ you can always turn an equation of this form back into a circle.

The equation of a line, on the other hand, is something like $dX+eY+f=0$. So if you combine them to $S+\lambda P=0$ you get

$$(X^2+Y^2)+(a+\lambda d)X+(b+\lambda e)Y+(c+\lambda f)=0$$

which again has the form of a circle equation. And since each individual term of the sum was zero for $A$ and $B$, their sum must be zero there as well. So you know that this will always be a circle through $A$ and $B$. And since you know it contains two real points, you don't have to worry about the $4c<a^2+b^2$ condition I wrote above, since if that were violated you'd have zero or imaginary radius, and couldn't have two real points located on the circle.

> Why should the circle have AB as diameter

It doesn't really matter what circle you start with. You could take *any* circle passing through $A$ and $B$, although a different choice would lead to a different value of $\lambda$. But the one with the diameter is easiest to compute.

As a variant, you can play the same game with two different circles passing through $A$ and $B$, and do $S_1+\lambda S_2=0$. Then you'd get an equation which starts with $(1+\lambda)(X^2+Y^2)$ but since you could as well divide the whole resulting equation by $(1+\lambda)$ it would still be a circle. (Except if $\lambda=-1$, then you'd have a line instead, so that happens if $A,B,C$ are collinear.) The only problem is that if $C$ already lies on $S_2$, you'd get a division by zero. To avoid that you could write $\lambda S_1+\mu S_2=0$, and you could compute these as e.g. $\lambda = S_2(C)$ and $\mu = -S_1(C)$ to ensure that $C$ satisfies the combined equation.

Answer (score 1):

You can see by plugging in the points that this equation is true on the points $A$, $B$, and $C$. By completing the square we can also show that it is the equation for a circle. The method works because there is a unique circle passing through $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is called “family of lines”.

[image]

It says, from A and B, form (using two-point form) P, the equation of AB.

It also says, form (using A and B as endpoints of diameter) S, the equation of the red circle. [There is a simple formula for doing that too.]

For different values of λ, S + λP = 0 represents a family of circles passing through A and B.

For a specific value of λ, that equation will be the circle that passes through C.

The co-ordinates of C can be used to determine that value of λ. Hence, the equation of the circle passing through A, B, C is known.