# Equation of a circle 3 points

Tags: circles

How does one solve the equation of a circle through three given points?...

(81,45) (81,-45) (85,0)

What is the solution to this???

I'm at a loss

Comment: We have several examples of solutions to such a question already. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018949/equation-of-circle-through-three-given-points, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827072/finding-an-equation-of-circle-which-passes-through-three-points, or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745145/finding-equation-of-a-circle-given-three-non-collinear-points -- take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the equation to be of the form $(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = r^2$ for some unknowns $x_0$, $y_0$ and $z_0$.

Plug in those three points for $(x, y)$ and solve for the unknowns.

Comment: I have told you the procedure, you should substitute your points for $x$ and $y$. For example, $(81-x_0)^2+(45-y_0)^2 = r^2$ and similarly others. The symmetry will give you $y_0 = 0$ easily as pointed out in the other comment. You should be able to carry out the computations.

Answer (score 0):

The general equation of a circle is 
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2,$$
with $(a,b)$ being the center of the circle, and $r$ being the radius.

Note that the first 2 points are symmetric about the $x-$axis, telling you that the y coordinate of the center is zero.  So you get 2 equations with 2 unknowns
$$(81-a)^2+45^2=r^2$$
$$(85-a)^2+0^2=r^2$$
You can subtract one equation from the other to solve for $a$, and then $r$ should be simple from there.

Comment: How do you mean subtract from one another?... That makes some sense 